# Rationality of Hilbert schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the Hilbert scheme of curves in $P^3$ with genus $g$ and degree $d$, $H_{g,d}$. Is this rational for some $g$ and $d$?

Edit: For which $(g,d)$ is this rational?

Comment: Surely it's rational for *some* $g$ and $d$, e.g. $(g,d)=(0,3)$ 
(rational normal cubics).  Not for all $(g,d)$, though, because 
for $g$ large enough ${\cal M}_g$ is of general type, and dominates
this Hilbert scheme once $d$ is large enough given $g$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks, I would be happy to accept that as an answer. Do you know a good reference for the higher genus case you describe?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Specifically I mean ... a reference for why $M_g$ is of general type, and for why when $d >> g$ $M_g$ dominates the corresponding Hilbert scheme. I'm also curious about the low degree cases as well, but I'm not sure where to study this material.

Comment: The fact that ${\cal M}_g$ is of general type for $g \geq 24$ 
is "a famous result due to Harris, Mumford and Eisenbud" as G.Farkas puts it at
https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~farkas/m22.pdf (which proves the
same result for $g=22$).

Comment: For $g>0$,
if $d \gg g$ then the sections of any divisor of degree $d$ embed $C$
as a curve of degree $d$ in a projective space of dimension $\geq 3$.
Now project to a generic ${\bf P}^3$ and you're done.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies You show that a fixed curve of genus $g$ can be embedded as a degree $d>>g$ curve in $P^3$. To get a flat family of space curves I think we can find a divisor in the universal curve over $M_g^0$ (curves with trivial automorphisms) which is degree d on each fiber, then use some form of relative Riemann-Roch to show it's very ample (maybe?), then embed this universal family in $M_g^0 \times P^N$, and argue that projecting to a particular$P^3$ still embeds the curves from an open set in $M_g^0$. I don't know how to find that divisor though ...maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Is all that really necessary?  All I'm saying is that the image of the
natural map $H_{d,g} \to {\cal M}_g$ is dense in ${\cal M}_g$;
so I need only check pointwise that every genus-$g$ curve is in the image
by finding some degree-$d$ embedding of it in ${\bf P}^3$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Oh okay -  I had it backwards, I thought you were trying to build a map from $M_g$. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[expanding on my comments above]

$H_{g,d}$ is rational for some but not all $(g,d)$.

A rational example is $H_{1,4}$: a quartic elliptic curve in
${\bf P}^3$ is the complete intersection of two quadrics, so
$H_{1,4}$ is just the Grassmanian of $2$-dimensional subspaces of the
$10$-dimensional space of quadrics.  Similarly for other cases where
the curve must be a smooth complete intersection; the simplest examples are
$(g,d) = (0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ if you allow curves that do not span ${\bf P}^3$.

On the other hand, given $g$, for $d$ large enough the Hilbert scheme
$H_{g,d}$ dominates the moduli space ${\cal M}_g$ of genus-$g$ curves,
because every such curve can be embedded in ${\bf P}^3$ with degree $d$.
(Use sections of a degree-$d$ divisor to embed in ${\bf P}^{d-g}$,
and project down to a generic ${\bf P}^3$.)
But ${\cal M}_g$ is of general type once $g \geq 24$ 
(Harris-Mumford-Eisenbud), so $H_{g,d}$ cannot be rational or even unirational
for such $g$.

The question of characterizing all $(g,d)$ for which $H_{g,d}$ is rational,
or even unirational, might be quite hard.  (I gather that "unirational"
can be more accessible; e.g. the Hilbert scheme $H_{0,3}$ of rational
normal cubics is certainly unirational but it's not obvious to me that
it is actually rational as I rashly claimed in my first comment.)

Comment: In fact $H_{0,3}$ is rational.  This is easier to see if you use the space of stable maps of degree $e$, genus $0$ curves to $\mathbb{P}^n$, say $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,0}(\mathbb{P}^n,e)$.  Then the standard torus action on $\mathbb{P}^n$ induces a torus action on the space of stable maps.  Using Bialynicki-Birula, you are reduced to showing rationality of certain fixed point loci; for $e=3$, the fixed point loci are just points.  Herb Clemens has a paper about this.